# Does Google Dialogflow's phone integration gateway has the DTMF cabability?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have integrated dialogflow's Phone Gateway with my agent. I want to know if dialogflow's phone integration gateway has DTMF capability? Example, I want something like, press 1 for this and press 2 for this? and then that bot should work on numbers entered by user? So, is there a way to get the numbers input from the user and get the value entered by the user in dialoglow response?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DTMF capability is available in the [Dialogflow CX Phone Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/phone-gateway) integration, but not available out-of-the-box in Dialogflow ES Phone Gateway.

Check the [DTMF for telephony integrations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#dtmf) documentation for instructions on how to implement DTMF in the Dialogflow CX [edition](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/editions).